# How to filter by file path in Google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to have the following script filter by file path. Ideally this should only show results from the folder marked 'GUEST' in my drive. Right now it shows those and anything else with the shared folder ID of this root (I do not want to use the GUEST folder ID because I will later use this to filter other users accessing my drive).

My google drive file path is as follows `Root/GUEST`

CODE UPDATED WITH ANSWER FROM COMMENTS:

```js
var folderId = "MyID"; // <--- Your shared folder ID

function doGet() {
    var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
    t.data = getFileList();
    return t.evaluate() .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);;


}




function getparams(e) {
    return zipping(typeof(e.fileId) == "string" ? [e.fileId] : e.fileId);
}

function getFileList() {
    var folderlist = (function(folder, folderSt, results) {
        var ar = [];
        var folders = folder.getFoldersByName("GUEST");
        while (folders.hasNext()) ar.push(folders.next());
        folderSt += folder.getId() + "#_aabbccddee_#";
        var array_folderSt = folderSt.split("#_aabbccddee_#");
        array_folderSt.pop()
        results.push(array_folderSt);
        ar.length == 0 && (folderSt = "");
        for (var i in ar) arguments.callee(ar[i], folderSt, results);
        return results;
    })(DriveApp.getFoldersByName("GUEST").next(), "", []);
    var localTimeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
    var filelist = [];
    var temp = {};
    for (var i in folderlist) {
        var folderid = folderlist[i][folderlist[i].length - 1];
        var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("GUEST");
        var files = folder.next().getFiles();
        while (files.hasNext()) {
            var file = files.next();
            temp = {
               folder_tree: function(folderlist, i) {
                  
                    if (i > 0) {
                        return "/" + [DriveApp.getFolderById(folderlist[i][j]).getName() for (j in folderlist[i])
                            if (j > 0)].join("/") + "/";
                    } else {
                        return "/";
                    }
                }(folderlist, i),
                file_id: file.getId(),
                file_name: file.getName(),
                file_size: file.getBlob().getBytes().length,
                file_created: Utilities.formatDate(file.getDateCreated(), localTimeZone, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"),
                file_updated: Utilities.formatDate(file.getLastUpdated(), localTimeZone, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"),
            };
            filelist.push(temp);
            temp = {}
        }
    }
   
var sortedlist = filelist.sort(function(e1, e2) {
        return (e1.folder_tree > e2.folder_tree ? 1 : -1) });
  

    return sortedlist;  

}




function zipping(fileId) {
    var blobs = [];
    var mimeInf = [];
    fileId.forEach(function(e) {
        try {
            var file = DriveApp.getFileById(e);
            var mime = file.getMimeType();
            var name = file.getName();
        } catch (e) {
            return e
        }
        Logger.log(mime)
        var blob;
        if (mime.indexOf('google-apps') > 0) {
            mimeInf =
                mime == "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" ? ["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", name + ".xlsx"] : mime == "application/vnd.google-apps.document" ? ["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", name + ".docx"] : mime == "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation" ? ["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", name + ".pptx"] : ["application/pdf", name + ".pdf"];
            blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + e + "/export?mimeType=" + mimeInf[0], {
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
                muteHttpExceptions: true
            }).getBlob().setName(mimeInf[1]);
        } else {
            blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + e + "?alt=media", {
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
                muteHttpExceptions: true
            }).getBlob().setName(name);
        }
        blobs.push(blob);
    });
    var zip = Utilities.zip(blobs, Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + '.zip');
    var bytedat = DriveApp.createFile(zip).getBlob().getBytes();
    return Utilities.base64Encode(bytedat);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   function postLogin(event) {
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        form.submit();

        event.preventDefault();
    }
</script> 
 <a href="" onClick="postLogin(event);" >Click!</a>
 <form id="myForm" action="MYEXECLINK" target="my_iframe"></form>
 <iframe id="my_iframe"name="my_iframe"  style= "width: 500px; height: 50%;" frameBorder="0" style="overflow:hidden"></iframe>
```

I tried to use an if statement at line 61, but it could not pull the variables for some reason (I think I'm not setting up my variables correctly):

```js
  if (filelist(folder_tree == "/GUEST/"){
    return sortedlist;}
  else
  {return null}
```

Does anyone know how to make this script filter by folder_tree? Hopefully by comparing it to a var (like user=guest)?

To clarify, here is the current result:

[image]

And this is the expected output:

[image]

Thanks for any help, I'll post updates as I work on it to clarify.

Comment: What is `the folder marked 'GUEST'`?

Comment: It is the folder that houses a set of files inside the root shared folder.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `the folder marked 'GUEST'`, is `GUEST` the folder name?

Comment: RIght, here is a temp link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HXlz9QTO-OaYSJtOF1SoJa89znDPkDRh?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could confirm that your shared link is the folder of the folder name `GUEST` and the folder has one Google Document file. You want to retrieve a file list in the folder of `GUEST` in your Google Drive. If my understanding is correct, I have one question. Do you required to check the subfolders in the folder of `GUEST`?

Comment: That is exactly right. No check for subfolders needed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to retrieve a file list under the specific folder with the folder name of `GUEST`. I could understand like this. If my understanding is correct, I think that you can retrieve the file list by `DriveApp.getFoldersByName("GUEST").next().getFiles()`. How about this? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: I was condsidering `getFoldersByName` earlier this week, but I'm I going to have rewrite all my `getfolderbyid` lines?

Comment: Figured it out, If you want go ahead and add you comment as an answer and I'll give you an upvote. Thanks! Updated my code with your advice

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that your script can be modified more simple. So I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve a file list under the specific folder.
- Subfolders in the specific folder are not required to be retrieved.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that your updated script works. But I thought that your script might be able to be modified more simple. So how about the following modification?

#### Modification point:

- In this modification, `getFileList()` was modified.
- In your script, at first, the folder tree is retrieved. Then, the files in all folders are retrieved. But in your situation, the folder tree is not required to be retrieved. By this, your script can be modified more simple.
- At first, "FileIterator" are retrieved with `DriveApp.getFoldersByName("GUEST").next().getFiles()`. Then, the values are retrieved from "FileIterator".

#### Modified script:

```
function getFileList() {
  var folderName = "GUEST";
  var files = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next().getFiles();
  var localTimeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var filelist = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var temp = {
      file_id: file.getId(),
      file_name: file.getName(),
      file_size: file.getBlob().getBytes().length,
      file_created: Utilities.formatDate(file.getDateCreated(), localTimeZone, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"),
      file_updated: Utilities.formatDate(file.getLastUpdated(), localTimeZone, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"),
    };
    filelist.push(temp);
  }
  return filelist;
}
```

#### References:

- [getFoldersByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename)
- [getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfiles)
- [Class FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)

Comment: Perfect, that is much more precise than what I had. Thanks!

Comment: @littlecoder Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.